ES Explorer is using over 50GB: how can I empty it without reinstalling it?
ES Explorer is using over 50GB on my iPhone 12 mini (~57.7GB):

I don't see anything in ES Explorer:

How can I empty it without reinstalling it?

Did you restart the phone to reset any counters which may be off? Did you empty its Recycle Bin?

@nohillside Thanks, you are right, I had missed the Recycle Bin (I had looked for one but missed it). You're welcome to post it an answer. I can add a screenshot to it. Thanks

ES File Explorer has a Recycle Bin in the cog wheel menu on top left, try to empty that one:

